# Real benefits of Java EE CDI

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

I'm new to Java EE and I'm wondering whats the real benefits of using CDI (@Named, @Inject). Of course I was asking the google. But I always got general answers like "loose coupling" and "better to test". But I think to get loose coupling no framework is needed.

In my little project I use three classes

```
public interface UserIf
{
    ...
}

@Named
public class User implements UserIf
{
     ...
}

public class Main
{
    @Inject
    UserIf user;
}
```

Now I can easily inject another Implementation of UserIf. But I also could do it with

```
public class Main
{
    UserIf user = new User();
}
```

This architecture is easy to change too. Just write another implementation of UserIf and change

```
UserIf user = new User();
```

to

```
UserIf user = new AnotherUserImpl();
```

I don't see a benefit of using CDI here. When I think about a bigger EAR project consisting of some EJBs and WARs, maybe it's easyer to reuse some modules (EJBs, WARs) if they are loose coupled. But as far as I know, it is not possible to use CDI if the classes are not in the same jar/war . So what would be a real setup where you get real benefits of using CDI?

Greetings Helmsen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that if you need for instance rename `AnotherUserImpl` or you want to switch to other implementation than you have to go to all classes which are using this impl and rename it. With CDI qualifiers you have everywhere

```
@Inject
@AnotherUser
private User user;
```

Client code doesn't know anything about implementation of the `User` so you are free to change it whatever you like on the business side and client won't even notice. Principle of loose coupling is that client which is using your API doesn't really know about implementation, this is configured externaly (think of CDI Producers or Spring XML configuration). There are also other benefits of CDI like Producers, Interceptors, new Transaction API, Alternatives or others.

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly bouncing closing this as non-constructive/opninionated only.  But there are some facts to help you understand a little bit better.

1. CDI does work across the JARs and WARs in an EAR.  The problem has to do with the definition of `@ApplicationScoped` where in an EAR, each of the EJB-JAR modules and WAR modules are technically defined as their own application.
2. The type of question you're asking is more about what is dependency injection/inversion of control rather than CDI specifically.  Not everyone will want to use these paradigms but realistically they are the norm.
3. The scoping model built in allow you to manage when an instance gets created more declaratively rather than programmatically.  In CDI, applying a scope to a bean is an annotation.  That bean then becomes readily available for you to use.